# Android: How to join two classes in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have two classes: User and following I want to join them, so I did this:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        users = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("following");
            innerQuery.whereEqualTo("username", "sara");
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("username", "follower_username", innerQuery);
            query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject user : ob) {
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) user.get("pic");
                UserInfo map = new UserInfo();
                map.setUserName((String) user.get("username"));
                map.setPic(image.getUrl());
                users.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here's the Logcat:

```
   04-16 10:49:17.586: W/dalvikvm(23216): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417d9898)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
   04-16 10:49:17.586: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):     ... 4 more
   04-16 10:49:17.996: D/AbsListView(23216): onDetachedFromWindow
   04-16 10:49:17.996: D/AbsListView(23216): unregisterIRListener() is called 
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216): Activity com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c02818 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c02818 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:449)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:285)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.MainActivity$RemoteDataTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:54)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at com.androidbegin.parselistviewimgtxt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
   04-16 10:49:18.026: E/WindowManager(23216):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It works fine if the user has one follower but if many, the app crashes Why ??
other than User class it works great

Comment: Did you call "registerSubclass" method to both classes?

Comment: @marson No I don't know this! what is this?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using subclasses of parse object, so the registersubclass method wouldn't need to be called..  The issue I see, or don't see, is any reference of Parse in the stack trace.

Comment: @Fosco I didn't post the whole log-cat because its too long I posted the exception only, Also I didn't undersatand your comment What are subclasses of Parse object and why do I need them ?